# Tengo inconveniente con angular 8 y canvas

Tags: html, typescript, canvas, angular8

No logro entender las dimensiones de la funcion drawImage() en typescript ya que no tengo mucho tiempo con angular 8 no encuentro muy facil la documentacion que requiero, claramente modificando mi codigo en esta linea:

html:`<canvas #canvas style="border-style: solid"></canvas> .`
ts:`this.ctx.drawImage(framePicture, 30, '0', 100, 8);`

consegui cambiar las dimensiones de mi marco y mi imagen pero necesito dejarla como en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi hoja app.component.ts ya que no necesite mas componentes adicionales todo lo he codificado aqui:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {FileUploader, FileSelectDirective} from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
import {NgbCarouselConfig, NgbModal, NgbModalConfig, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {WebcamImage, WebcamModule} from 'ngx-webcam';
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import {$} from "protractor";

const URL = 'http://localhost:4000/api/upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('file', {static: true}) uploadPhoto: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('frames_section', {static: true}) framesSection: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('canvas', {static: true}) canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  @ViewChild('screen', {static: true}) screen: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
  }

  imageSticker: any = [];
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  url = '';
  title = 'lights-app';
  public imagePath;
  public stickerPath;
  public message: string;
  public photo;

  frames: any[] = [{one: null}, {two: null}, {three: null}, {four: null}, {frame: null}];
  framesSticker: any[] = [{one: null}, {two: null}, {three: null}, {four: null}, {five: null}];

  public webcamImage: WebcamImage = null;

  // webcam snapshot trigger
  private trigger: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL, itemAlias: 'photo'});

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

  }
  addSticker() {
    // console.log("Hola mundo");

  }
  downloadCanvasImage($event) {
    // let generatedImage = screen.toDataURL();
        // let a = document.createElement('a');
        // a.href = generatedImage;
        // a.download = null;
        // a.click();
  }

  chargeImage(files) {
    const mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      this.message = 'Only images are supported.';
      return;
    }
    this.imagePath = files;
  }

  showImage(frame, content) {
    if (this.imagePath && !this.webcamImage) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.imagePath[0]);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.frames = [];
        this.frames[frame] = reader.result;
        this.frames[`four`] = reader.result;
        this.frames[`frame`] = 'frame-' + frame + ' col-12';
        this.frames[`clean_frame`] = 'frame-' + frame;
        // @ts-ignore
        // const photo = new Image(100, 200);
        // photo.src = this.frames[`four`].toString();
        // photo.onload = () => {
        //   this.ctx.drawImage(photo, 1, 1, 600, 600);
        // };
        const framePicture = new Image(200, 1000);
        let srcFrame = '';
        switch (this.frames[`clean_frame`]) {
          case 'frame-one':
            srcFrame = 'assets/marco1.png';
            break;
          case 'frame-two':
            srcFrame = 'assets/marco2.png';
            break;
          case 'frame-three':
            srcFrame = 'assets/marco3.png';
            break;
        }
        framePicture.src = srcFrame;
        framePicture.onload = () => {
          this.ctx.drawImage(framePicture, 30, '0', 100, 8);
        };
        const photo = new Image(100, 25);
        photo.src = this.frames[`four`];
        photo.onload = () => {
          this.ctx.drawImage(photo, 8, 0, 0, 8);
        };
      };
    } else if (!this.imagePath && this.webcamImage) {
      this.frames = [];
      this.frames[frame] = this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl;
      this.frames[`four`] = this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl;
      this.frames[`frame`] = 'frame-' + frame + ' col-12 frame-four';
    } else {
      this.message = 'No existe una foto';
      this.modalService.open(content, {}).result.then((result) => {
      });
    }
  }

  public triggerSnapshot($event, content): void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.trigger.next();
    this.photo = false;
    this.message = null;
    this.modalService.open(content, {windowClass: 'main-modal-class'}).result.then((result) => {
      if (result === 'repeat') {
        this.photo = true;
      }
    });
  }

  public get triggerObservable(): Observable<void> {
    return this.trigger.asObservable();
  }

  photoClickTrigger(event) {
    const sub: HTMLElement = this.uploadPhoto.nativeElement;
    sub.click();
  }

  takePicture(action, $event) {
    this.photo = action;
  }

  public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
  }

}
```

Ahora se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">

        <div class="navcontent">
            <div>
                <div class="responsive embed-responsive"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="img"><img src="assets/lightbytenargb.png " class="img-logo"></div>
                <ul class="nav responsive">
                    <li class="item"><a href="#" class="itemlink">Productos</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#" class="itemlink">Asesoría</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#" class="itemlink">Más Vivas</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#" class="itemlink button-shop">Comprar</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#" class="itemlink button">Muestra Gratis</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!---Container-Main--->
    <div class="container-fluid margin-container center-padding">
        <!--section-1-->
        <div>

            <!--Carrusel-->
            <div>
                <ngb-carousel>
                    <ng-template ngbSlide>
                        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img src="assets/slide2.jpg" alt="Random first slide">
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template ngbSlide>
                        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img src="assets/slide1.jpg" alt="Random second slide">
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template ngbSlide>
                        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img src="assets/slide3.jpg" alt="Random third slide">
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-carousel>
            </div>
            <!--Carrusel-->
            <br> <br> <br> <br>
            <div class="container-title1">
                <p class="title-pink1"> Pero más allá de todo eso, significa que hoy <span class="title-pink"> es un gran día y lo tenemos que celebrar  </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <br> <br> <br> <br>
            <div class="margen">
                <img src="assets/flechaabajo.png">
            </div>
            <br> <br>
            <div class="container-title1">
                <p class="title-pink1"> ¡Siéntete <span class="title-pink"> orgullosa </span> y muéstrate <span class="title-pink">como eres! </span></p>
            </div>
            <br> <br>
            <div class="margen" id="photo_tittle">
                <img src="assets/creaaqui.png">
            </div>
            <br> <br>
            <div class="margen">
                <img src="assets/flechaabajo.png">
            </div>
            <br> <br>
        </div>

        <!--section-2-->
        <div>
            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
            <div class="margen">
                <div class="title-pink2"><span class="title-pink">  1. </span> Sube tu foto</div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div>
                        <input type="file" id="upload" style="display: none;" #file (change)="chargeImage(file.files)">
                        <a class="itemlink col-6" href="#frames_section" (click)="photoClickTrigger($event)">Elige una foto</a>
                        <a class="itemlink col-6" href="#photo_section" (click)="takePicture(true,$event)">Toma una foto</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="photo" id="photo_section">
                <div>
                    <webcam [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)">

                    </webcam>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="itemlink col-6" href="#" (click)="triggerSnapshot($event, content)">Tomar foto</a>
                    <a class="itemlink col-6" href="#photo_tittle" (click)="takePicture(false, $event)">Cancelar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="margen">
                <div class="title-pink2"><span class="title-pink" id="frames_section"> 2. Personaliza </span> tu foto
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="textcolor-gray"><span class="textcolor-graydark">  ¡Escoge  </span>tu marco!</div>

            <div class="row subetufoto-nav">
                <div [ngClass]="frames['one'] ? 'height-auto' : 'height-man'" id="frameOne" class="col-3 frame-one" (click)="showImage('one', content)">
                    <img class="img-up" [src]="frames['one']" style="width: 100%;" *ngIf="frames['one']">
                </div>

                <div [ngClass]="frames['two'] ? 'height-auto' : 'height-man'" id="frameTwo" class="col-3 frame-two" (click)="showImage('two', content)">
                    <img class="img-up" [src]="frames['two']" *ngIf="frames['two']">
                </div>

                <div [ngClass]="frames['three'] ? 'height-auto' : 'height-man'" id="frameThree" class="col-3 frame-three" (click)="showImage('three', content)">
                    <img class="img-up" [src]="frames['three']" *ngIf="frames['three']">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br> <br> <br>
            <div class="textcolor-gray"><span class="textcolor-graydark">  ¡Escoge  </span>tu sticker!</div>
            <br> <br> <br>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ngb-carousel class="offset-1" interval="0">
                    <ng-template ngbSlide>
                        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img src="assets/masfeliz.png" alt="Random first slide">
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template ngbSlide>
                        <div  class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img (click)="addSticker()" src="assets/masviva.png" alt="Random second slide">
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template ngbSlide>
                        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img src="assets/estrellas.png" alt="Random third slide">
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-carousel>
            </div>


        </div>
        <!--section-3-->
        <div><br> <br> <br> <br>


            <!--------------------------- Comentario------------->
            <br> <br> <br>
            <div class="textcolor-gray"><span class="textcolor-graydark">  ¡Tu foto</span> está lista!</div>
            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
            <div>

            </div>

            <div class="row subetufoto-nav">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="text-center" >
                        <canvas #canvas style="border-style: solid"></canvas>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 ">
                    <div class="row">

                        <button (click)="downloadCanvasImage($event)" class="btn btn-danger">Descarga tu foto!</button>
                    </div>
                    <br> <br>
                    <div class="row">Comparte tu foto en redes</div>
                    <br> <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="assets/instagram.png" class="col-3">
                        <img src="assets/facebook.png" class="col-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br> <br> <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="margen">
            <img src="assets/usanuestroscanales.png" class="imagen-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>


    <!--MODAL TEMPLATE -->
    <ng-template #content let-modal>
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <div class="snapshot" *ngIf="webcamImage">
                <h2>Luce bien!</h2>
                <img [src]="webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p *ngIf="message">
                    {{ message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" *ngIf="webcamImage" (click)="modal.close('repeat')">Tomar otra
      foto
    </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" *ngIf="webcamImage" (click)="modal.close()">De acuedo!
    </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" *ngIf="!webcamImage" (click)="modal.close()">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

</body>

</html>
```

Realmente no tenog muy claro como deberia construir el boton para descargar el canvas completo en el directorio que el usuario quiera elegir.

Comment: Puedes montar una version en stackblitz.com? Ayudaría verlo funcionando

Comment: Claro dejame miro como lo hago..

Comment: `drawImage` no tiene nada que ver con `Angular`, es `JavaScript` y pertenece a la API de `canvas`. [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) puedes encontrar la referencia, consúltala, que te explica como dibujar tu imagen.